# onSizeChanged returns width, but not height

Tags: java, android, layout

I need to get height and width of my View and I have followed examples given here with subclassing View and using onSizeChanged(...).
But what is very strange is that onSizeChanged gives me the correct width, but height is always 0. Here's my subclass:

```
public class MyView extends TextView {
int xMax=0; int yMax=0;Context c;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.c=context;

}
@Override
   public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {

      xMax = w;
      yMax = h;
```

My Activity class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView dummyView = new MyView(this);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainmtc);
    ll.addView(dummyView);
```

and my XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainmtc" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"
androiad:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's normal, there is no content in your view so the height is 0.

Try to add some text in your custom textview and height will change

```
TextView dummyView = new MyView(this);
dummyView.setText("Hello");
```

Device screen dimensions : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Comment: Will do (I am new to StackOverflow). But what is the solution to my problem? All examples found never mention that this happens?

Comment: Did that now, but height is still 0. When rotating the device I get changing width, but not for height. I need to get the dimensions of the device screen. Am I taking the right approach?

Comment: Device screen dimensions can be retrieved by the DisplayMetrics class